# What do you call the application running in a pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, architecture

In a typical theoretical system, I would call the different applications that make up the system *nodes*. However this is confusing in a Kubernetes cluster system for two reasons:

1. "Node.js" is often shortened to "node", and not all of the *nodes* in my system are "Node.js" processes.
2. Kubernetes uses the word "node" to refer to physical components in the cluster.

So the question is, what terminology is used to describe the subject that you would run on a pod? Are they projects? Processes? Application nodes? Applications?

None of the above sound right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pods contain one (or rarer more) application(s):

> A Pod models an application-specific "logical host": it contains one or more application containers which are relatively tightly coupled.

[Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/)

In the Kubernetes universe, [Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/) are the physical or virtual machines that your cluster is running on. Pods run on the Nodes. I suggest to avoid the term Node for applications.

Comment: So we're thinking that an "Application" is likely what it should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it would be a "service" (although it clashes with k8s service) or a "microservice"

Comment: Yeah using any k8s resource names is not going to work. Some parts of a system aren't exactly a service either (like a database, or a running cronjob, etc)